# Large safe prime number in SSHv2 DH key exchange

Tags: ssh, wireshark

Per RFC 4419, before the client DH Key Exchange Init message, server will send a large safe prime number (p) and generator for the subgroup (g) to client. I am looking at a wireshark packet captures but don't see them. I see following in Server Key Exchange Init message (see pic)
[image]

Where are the `p` and `g`? Am I missing something?

[edit] The next two packets are

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would be using `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1`, it would be below in the next packets. What is visible in the screenshot is [Algorithm Negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-7.1).

The key exchange starts just after this section when we go into the [DH Key Exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-8). But these numbers are passed only if with the above key exchange method! (Group Exchange -- different algorithms can work with fixed groups).

Under the [section 3 of RFC4419](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4419#section-3), you can see the message `SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP` from server, which sends the `p` and `g` to the client.

In your example, you are using either `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` or `diffie-hellman-group14-sha1`, which is defined in RFC4253 and is using fixed group and primes.

Comment: I don't see them in next two packets either. The very next packet is DH key exchange init that has "e" in it and then server sends DH key exchange reply that has KEX DH host key, DH server f and DH H signature. so it looks that they are 3 and 4 of section 3 of RFC 4419. For reference , i will edit the question and include next two packets snippets. Thanks

Comment: As you can see in your screenshot, your kex algorithms are `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` and `diffie-hellman-group14-sha1`, therefore you are not using the `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1` (and the RFC 4419) and the DH key exchange is done using fixed groups and primes.

Comment: thanks that cleared the confusion. Do you know how i can get the public key from the Kex DH Host key? It seems that the public key that is stored in my local database is different than what is seen in wireshark packet. I tried doing MD5 hash of the public key(stored in local db) but its still different.

Comment: In wireshark, you see the public key in hexadecimal format, but the one stored in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` is most probably in `base64` encoding. Therefore the hashes are different.